# Autoform manual submit

Tags: javascript, android, forms, meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm using Autoform for my meteor app and I want to submit the form manually using javascript. I've tried:

```
$('form#myFormId').submit();
```

and

```
document.forms['myFormId'].submit();
```

and neither of them work. The form is not being submitted and none of the call back functions (eg. onSuccess) are being called. I want to do this because I want to inject javascript in my android webview, which I'm using to display my website in my android app.

EDIT: I think the form is being submitted, but none of the Autoform functions are being called, ie. nothing is being inserted into the collection the callbacks aren't working. Right now, it just redirects to the same webpage with the input content in the url (since I didn't specify an action for my form, since I don't need one if I'm using autoform and meteor).

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with **meteor-autoform**, a good thing to do is to always enable the debug mode while in development:

```
if (Meteor.isClient)
    AutoForm.debug()
```

in some development.js file somewhere in your app.

Now, having your **autoform** not triggering the methods attached can occur when:

- the *id* of your form is not unique on your page and **autoform** is hooked to this other *id* and doesn't detect your form submission. I have a strong feeling this could be the case here.
- you have some non-optional things in your schema preventing the form to be submitted as long as all the mandatory fields are not populated.
- you have somewhere in your events.js a *click yourformbutton* event being called, preventing the actual autoform event listener to fire when submit (but this should not be the case since submitting through `.submit()` does not work either.

Another good way to understand what's going on is to use autoform hooks like: `onSubmit: function(insertDoc, updateDoc, currentDoc)`, `onSuccess: function(result)`, `onError: function(error)`. On submit is particularly interesting to examine your data flow.

More details about those hooks here : https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the best approach, but here is how I was able to manually submit my form. [Inspired by this](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#non-collection-forms) approach.

I have the auto form defined like so

```
{{#autoForm schema=postFormSchema id="formId"}}
```

Then I defined an `onSubmit` hook to with `return false` so that I can manually call my [meteor method](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/methods) from my client.

```
onSubmit: function(insertDoc, updateDoc, currentDoc) {
  //Do some custom async js here as required,
  //Then I call my meteor method directly from obSubmit hook
  Meteor.call("addPost", insertDoc, function (error, post) {});
  //reset the form.
  AutoForm.resetForm('formId');
  return false;
}
```

**Note:** onSubmit is not called if you have `type=method` and are using a meteor method for your AutoForm submission. [mentioned here](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks)

The advantage of doing it like this is the AutoForm handles validation, and attempts submission and I can perform some customizations in the `onSubmit` method.
(Ensure to call `check` on the server methods as well using your `AutoFormSchema`).